# Gnome Shell integration native host connector will not work with Firefox 58

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, firefox-extensions

Ubuntu 17.10 (xorg), gnome 3.26.2, Firefox 58.0 (64 bit).  I have installed gnome-shell-extensions, chrome-gnome-shell, and the browser add ons for both Google Chrome and for Firefox.  In Firefox the only add on/extension I have installed is gnome-shell-integration.

The integration with https://extensions.gnome.org works just fine with Google Chrome.  However, with Firefox, I keep getting this error message:  "Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector."

What must I do to make this work with Firefox?

Comment: What's your `chrome-gnome-shell` version? (Output of `apt-cache policy chrome-gnome-shell | grep -i installed`?)

Comment: pomsky:  9-0ubuntu1

Comment: Looks like it is non-reproducible, [OP mentioned in their answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1013930/480481) that it started working on its own after some days.

Comment: Shortly after I stated that it started working on its own, the original problem returned.  Since then it has never worked for me.

Comment: Oh, that's not good. Hope you have switched to a supported version (e.g. 18.04) already as 17.10 is past its EoL and now it's working with an updated version of Firefox.

Comment: Sadly, I am on 18.04 and most current version of Firefox and gnome shell, but still having the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

maybe - the easiest way is to install:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

Then

```
cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell
```

if there is NO such folder, then please:

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/gnome-shell
```

then:

```
cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell
mkdir extensions
```

and extract your downloaded `.zip` file from the homepage of `gnome-extensions` to the `extensions` folder by clicking on the zip file and show hidden files and folders by either pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> or clicking on the upper right symbol with the 3 lines and choosing *show all files/hidden files* (I do not exactly know the English text version).

Then open up your files - choose *other locations* - look for hidden files and folders again and click on `.local` and then upon `share` and then upon `gnome-shell` and then upon `extensions` and RIGHT-click upon the file `metadata.json` and open with some text-editor and at the bottom after `uuid` please enter `/home/username/.local/share/gnome-extensions/` where `username` is your real username... or in your sub-folder you MAY have created in case you want to use several extensions more..

Then, please restart your computer.

Although this sounds a little weird this got my gnome-extensions (in this case suspend-button) to work properly (after 1 hour work , haha :))

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I should mark this as an answer.....

For the past couple months, I could not get the browser add-on to work in Firefox as I described in my original post.  Day after day I would try, but it would not work.  Now, today (March 11, 2018) it works for some unknown, mysterious reason.